# PHPUnit losing class name (ReflectionClass class does not exist error)

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm trying to get PHPUnit working; I haven't used it before. If I run phpunit in the CLI, it works, but via a script (which is what I'm looking for) it doesn't. This is the output I get (note the two spaces after Class):

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class  does not exist' in /usr/local/share/pear/PHPUnit/Util/Test.php:295
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/local/share/pear/PHPUnit/Util/Test.php(295): ReflectionClass->__construct('')
#1 /usr/local/share/pear/PHPUnit/Util/Test.php(576): PHPUnit_Util_Test::parseTestMethodAnnotations(false, false)
#2 /usr/local/share/pear/PHPUnit/Util/Test.php(350): PHPUnit_Util_Test::getBooleanAnnotationSetting(false, false, 'backupGlobals')
#3 /usr/local/share/pear/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php(458): PHPUnit_Util_Test::getBackupSettings(false, false)
#4 /usr/local/share/pear/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php(834): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite::createTest(Object(ReflectionClass), false)
#5 /usr/local/share/pear/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php(212): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestMethod(Object(ReflectionClass), Object(ReflectionMethod))
#6 /usr/local/share/pear/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php(315): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->__construct(Object(ReflectionClass))
#7 /var/www/www.s in /usr/local/share/pear/PHPUnit/Util/Test.php on line 295
```

It appears that the class name is being lost in `addTestMethod`. This is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';

class MyTestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testSubtraction() {
        $this->assertEquals(2 - 2, 0);
    }
    public function testAddition() {
        $this->assertEquals(2 + 2, 4);
    }
}
$c = new MyTestCase();

$suite = new PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite();
$suite->addTestSuite('MyTestCase');
PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner::run($suite);
```

Am I setting things up wrong?

Here are the versions:

```
Installed packages, channel pear.phpunit.de:
============================================
Package            Version State
File_Iterator      1.3.3   stable
PHPUnit            3.7.21  stable
PHPUnit_MockObject 1.2.3   stable
PHP_CodeCoverage   1.2.11  stable
PHP_Timer          1.0.4   stable
PHP_TokenStream    1.1.5   stable
Text_Template      1.1.4   stable
```

PHP 5.4

Reflection does work, I use that in my own scripts. Hopefully it's something with my setup, I really don't want to have to modify PHPUnit...surely it works elsewhere.

Comment: Did you solve this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong:

```
'Class  does not exist'
       ^
       `- normally the classname is given here
```

As you can see your error message is either missing something or PHPUnit tried to create a testcase out of nothing. Check you don't have some superfluous / incomplete files in your tests folder. Or something like that along the line. It's just a guess based on the error message, if I were you I would tackle this down in a debug session to actually find out what happens. This includes remove-debugging the testing session and stepping through and probably adding debug code into the phpunit install. Take care and backups.